# Connecting to a MS Access database from PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, ms-access, pdo, odbc

My client has been running a Windows server for years but we are now moving to a separate Linux machine for the web app I have created for them. Currently we run PHP on the Windows server on which we are able to connect to an MDB file that is on the same disk. This is a file from an external party, the web app uses MySQL. In the new setup we have a Linux web server (Apache/MySQL/PHP) and a Windows 2016 server which are connected via VPN and we have mounted a share on the Windows server in which the MDB file is located. So far, so good, however I can't seem to query the MDB file. The connection is made, not error there, but every query I run returns an error or nothing not sure. This is my code:

```
<?php
$db=new PDO("odbc:Driver=MDBTools; DBQ=/mnt/<dir>/<file>.mdb;");
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM <table>;");

$return=array();
if($query) {
     while($result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $return[]=$result;
     }
}else $return['error']=1;

//close
$query=null;
$db=null;

print_r($return);
?>
```

Currently everything returns error > 1.

PDO throws the following error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08001]: Client unable to establish connection: 1 Couldn't parse SQL (SQLExecute[1] at /build/php7.2-pRoOsC/php7.2-7.2.24/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:260)
```

Comment: have you got PDO set up to throw exceptions when problems occur? Getting an actual error message would be very helpful here.

Comment: @ADyson can you give me some pointers?

Comment: It's already in the manual! https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Adding try/catch to the mix still shows error > 1.

Comment: Did you add the `->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` as well?

Comment: Aha... I thought the connection was fine, but this is saying "no": Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08001]: Client unable to establish connection: 1 Couldn't parse SQL (SQLExecute[1] at /build/php7.2-pRoOsC/php7.2-7.2.24/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:260)

Comment: @ADyson all tips are welcome... I'm sure the location is correct, my script first checks if the file exists and the file doesn't need any user credentials (for now). I have also tried putting the MDB file on the server, with the same result.

Comment: Are you planning on updating this .mdb file, or are you just going to read from it?

Comment: @GordThompson It's going to be read/write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem was removing the ; from the query.